# How to make the text above recylcerview scroll when when you scroll recylerview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which is have title textview and recylerview below it.
It all works good. But I am trying to make the whole thing scrollable. Meaning that if I scroll down the rcylerview when new items are added, I want the title textview to scroll up (disappears) as if it is part of the recylerview

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:text="Near me"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvVideos"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I know that I can fake it so item 1 of the recylerview has a different layout which is the title text but I am hoping there is a better option so I don't have to deal with edge cases of number of items and manipulating positions

Comment: Have you tried using a `NestedScrollView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap both the textview and recycler view in a **NestedScrollView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
                    android:text="Textview"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I hope this helps...**Cheers**